# Program Upload Loading problem

Tags: arduino-nano

Please help me about this program uploading problem.
 Arduino: 1.6.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P"

Sketch uses 930 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM1": The system cannot find the file specified.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: did you select the right port in Tools menu?

Answer (score 0):

It can have many options, the main reason is it cannot communicate with the Nano.

I try to create a list with options:

- Hardware issues

  - Nano is broken (solution: change Nano)
  - USB cable is broken (solution: change cable)
  - USB port is broken (solution: change USB port)
- Software issues

  - USB port 'corrupt' (solution: use another USB port)
  - USB connection incorrect (solution: reconnect USB cable)
  - IDE is corrupt (solution: reinstall IDE)
  - Nano in illegal state (solution: reset/reconnect power of Nano)
  - Serial communication is used (remove RX/TX wires)